# Connecting QTableView selectionChanged signal produces segfault with PyQt

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, qtableview

I have a QTableView in a PyQt application, and I want to keep track of when the selection changes. I've tried connecting the signal to a slot as follows (using the advice on [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html):

```
self.view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selChanged)
```

where the slot it is connected to is defined as:

```
def selChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        print "Sel changed"
```

However, whenever I load the QMainWindow on which the QTableView resides, I get an immediate segmentation fault.

Am I doing something silly here?

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong in the code you show. Perhaps the issue is somewhere else? Can you post a full example with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed now, it turned out that I was using an old version of Qt on that machine - which seemed to cause the crash.

The moral of the story is: if your code is crashing for no sensible reason, check all of your dependencies (in this case Qt and PyQt) are up-to-date.

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar problem and the fix was here:
[PySide: Segfault(?) when using QItemSelectionModel with QListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211430/pyside-segfault-when-using-qitemselectionmodel-with-qlistview)

Namely, replace:

```
self.view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selChanged)
```

with two commands:

```
selectionModel = self.view.selectionModel()
selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.selChanged)
```

Not sure why this works, frankly.