# PyQt (Python and QT) How to detect when an item in Tableview has been selected/highlighted?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

So guys I need some help in regards to PyQt. I'm relatively new to it and still learning. My question is about whether there is some signal that detects when an item has been selected using the arrows ? For  example below this code works perfectly for calling my current_selection() method when something is clicked on by the cursor ? Thanks for reading!

self.project_table_view.clicked.connect(self.current_selection)

Comment: You could try to connect to either `currentItemChanged` or `itemSelectionChanged`

Comment: Your `QTableView` has a [selection model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). The selection model has a [`selectionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal.

Comment: thuga I saw the selection model and selectionChanged signal mentioned elsewhere but don't see anywhere on how to implement them properly in Python ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to thuga and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803315/connecting-qtableview-selectionchanged-signal-produces-segfault-with-pyqt), I got a solution using
these two lines

selectionModel = self.view.selectionModel()
selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.selChanged)